# react state updated undefined and render nothing

Tags: reactjs

I'm still learning react. The data is retrieved from the redux action and store as props. My problem is that my variable is undefined after a filter function executed. What I am trying to do is using the data from redux action, and display those variable. The state of the component turn out to be undefined and nothing display on view. Does anyone know how to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xyJn.png

```
1) Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure 'this.state.currentTour' as it is undefined.
```

```
[
  { 
    "_id": "12345",
    "name": "I am first tour",
    "description": "Iasofisajdaiosjdioasdmoias",
    "imageUrl": "https://something1.jpg",
    "dates": [
      "2021-06-19T09:00:00.000Z",
      "2021-07-20T09:00:00.000Z",
    ],
  },
  { 
    "_id": "67890",
    "name": "I am second tour",
    "description": "cvxbcvbcxbcvbcxb",
    "imageUrl": "https://something2.jpg",
    "dates": [
      "2023-01-12T09:00:00.000Z",
      "2023-04-22T01:00:00.000Z",
    ],
  },
   
  //.....rest data
]
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Tour.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Tour extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            currentTour: {},
        }

        this.findSingletour = this.findSingletour.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        const tourId = this.props.match.params._id;
        let FilteredTour = this.findSingletour(tourId);

        // console.log(FilteredTour); ----> undefined
        if (FilteredTour !== this.state.currentTour) {
            this.setState({
                currentTour: FilteredTour
            });
        }
    }

    findSingletour = (tourId) => {
        const notYetFilterTours = this.props.tours.tourState.data;
        let filtered = [];

        if (notYetFilterTours) {
            filtered = notYetFilterTours.find((tour) => {
                if (tour.id === tourId) return true;

                return filtered; // --->  actual object get back { id: '...' , name: '...', ..... }
            });
        }
    };

    render() {

        const {
            name,
            description,
            imageUrl,
            dates,
            } = this.state.currentTour || {}; // ---> undefined


        return (
            <div>
                <span>{name}</span>
                <span>{description}</span>
                <span>{imageUrl}</span>
                <span>{dates[0]}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    tours: state.tourContainer,
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(Tour);
```

Comment: in filter `"_id": "67890",` use `_id` not `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I don't know does it helpful or not, but it's work for me

1. For warning `Can't perform a React state update...`
   => to not see this warning  add code below, and add `if(!this.mounted) return;` before where ever you use `this.setState`

   ```
    private mounted = false as boolean;
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.mounted = false
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.mounted = true
    }
   ```
2. I see your function findSingletour() should return default value for it.
   Example:

   ```
    findSingletour = (tourId) => {
        const notYetFilterTours = this.props.tours.tourState.data;
        let filtered = [];

        if (notYetFilterTours) {
            filtered = notYetFilterTours.find((tour) => {
                if (tour.id === tourId) return true;

                return filtered; // --->  actual object get back { id: '...' , name: '...', ..... }
            });
        }
        return filtered; // or something else cause I saw you had return bool or filtered
        // If you do not return here result maybe is undefined
    };
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 'filtered' contains an object now but this.state.currentTour is still an empty object and is not updated.